# HTML/Javascript button is not working in Safari (iPhone, macbook) but works in other browsers (Chrome and Samsung Internet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a button that uses Ajax and JavaScript to send info to the database. It works fine on Chrome and on Android (my Galaxy Note 8). But the weird thing is, I used the exact same syntax (but different function) for another button, and that worked on every device. Help!!

I've tried changing the `.click(function)` to `.on('click touchstart')` in case the click wasn't being registered on mobile, but that wasn't it. I've also tried replacing the function with just a simple alert, but the button click still wasn't being registered. It's weird because I have another button with the same properties but it works perfectly fine!

here is my code:

JS:

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function(e) { 
    if ($.trim($('#message').val()).length > 0) {     
        var message = $("#message").val(); 
        $('input[name=message').val(''); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'includes/sendChat.inc.php', 
            type: 'POST', data: { umessage: message } 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div id="messagecon"> 
        <h3 id="msghead">Community</h3> 
            <div id="chatBox"> 
                <div id="chatDisplay"></div> 
            </div> 
            <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Say something"><br> 
        <button type="button" style="z-index: 99;" id="sendBtn">Send</button> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

(different file named "sendChat.inc.php")

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include ("dbh.inc.php"); $idUser = $_SESSION['userId']; 
$nameUser = $_SESSION['accName']; 
$umessage = $_POST['umessage']; 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO chat 
    (user,message,name,time) VALUES ('$idUser','$umessage','$nameUser','$date')"; 
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
?>}
```

This is the code for the button that works across all devices:

JS:

```
$('#addnewbtn').click(function(e) {                 
    if ($.trim($('#addInput').val()).length > 0) {
        var todoText = $("#addInput").val();
        $('input[name=task]').val('');
        $('.scrollpanel').append('<li class="item">'+todoText+'<span style="float: right;"><div class="overlay"><input type="checkbox" class="markdone"></input><img class="trash" src="images/trash.png"/></div></span></li>');
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/add.inc.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { task: todoText }
        });
        setTimeout(displayList, 100);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="todolist">
    <h1 class="header">To Do</h1>
    <ul class="tasks">
        <div id="displayList"></div>
    </ul>
    <div class="addnew">
        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Add a new task" class="input" id="addInput" autocomplete="off" required="true">
        <button type="button" style="z-index: 99;"class="submit" id="addnewbtn">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is this extra `{` at `{$('#sendBtn')`

Comment: oh sorry i must have accidentally added that when trying to format the code on here. it is not in my original file

Comment: is your javascript above the HTML in your original code? Maybe the script is being executed before the page finished loading, and so the click function can't be applied to the button

Comment: yes it is located above it

Comment: then try either adding it below the HTML or wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function() { your click listener here });`

Comment: oh sorry i do have it in a '$(document).ready(function() {' i didn't include it in there though^

Comment: Hope you have resolved the issue, it seems to be browser script might be blocked.